# Pass var to vue router in meta

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I have a route created with vue-router.

```
{
    path: '/events/:id',
    component: Event,
    name: 'Event',
    meta: {
        title: 'Design Web'
    }
},
```

In "meta", I give it the name of my page.

I can call the title of my page by doing this: `$route.meta.title`

But now, I'm facing a problem. In the title of my page, I would like to pass a variable (the name of my event).

```
meta: {
  title: $nameOfEvent
}
```

How to do ?

Thank you

Comment: Is the name of your event related to the :id param you have access to in $route.params.id?

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is possible if you define the title attribute as a function :

```
{
  meta: { title: route => { /* return custom title based on route, store or anything */ } }
}
```

and

```
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  if (to.meta.title) {
    document.title = to.meta.title(to);
  }
  next();
})
```

Codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/roRmdo?editors=1111 (you need to inspect inner iframe to see the title change).

or create a directive:

```
Vue.directive('title', {
  inserted: (el, binding) => document.title = binding.value,
  update: (el, binding) => document.title = binding.value
})
```

Then use that directive on the router-view component:

```
<router-view v-title="title" ></router-view>
```

Component:

```
export default {
  data(){
    return {
      title: 'This will be the title'
    }
  }
}
```

Source: https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router/issues/914